# Operator overloading template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

So I have a little class that implements a matrix. Everything works well, except whatever gave me the reason to post here. I've explained more about the problem in the actual code, using comments. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help! This is not the entire program, but it is big enough so that it can compile on its own.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

template<class type_t, unsigned Rows, unsigned Columns>
class matrix
{
private:
    std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<type_t>> elements;

public:
    type_t contents[Rows][Columns];

    matrix() {}

    matrix(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<type_t>> &container)
        : elements(container)
    {
        unsigned i = 0;
        for (const auto &el : elements)
        {
            unsigned j = 0;
            for (const auto &num : el)
            {
                contents[i][j] = num;
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    unsigned rows() { return Rows; }
    unsigned columns() { return Columns; }

    type_t &operator()(const unsigned &i, const unsigned &j)
    {
        return contents[i][j];
    }

    template<unsigned rws, unsigned cls>
    auto operator*(matrix<type_t, rws, cls> &mat)
    {
        matrix<type_t, Rows, 3> ret_mat;  //OK, but only in case the return matrix has 3 columns
    matrix<type_t, Rows, mat.columns()> ret_mat; //Error. This is the desired result
                                //The error message tells me it needs to be a compile-time constant
                                //it's pretty obvious why the first works and what the problem is
                                //but i still have no idea how to get past this

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < this->rows(); ++i)
        {
            for (unsigned j = 0; j < mat.columns(); ++j)
            {
                for (unsigned in = 0; in < 2; ++in)
                    ret_mat.contents[i][j] += this->contents[i][in] * mat.contents[in][j];
            }
        }

        return ret_mat;
    }
};

int main()
{
    matrix<int, 4, 2> mat = { { 7, 3 },{ 2, 5 },{ 6, 8 },{ 9, 0 } };
    matrix<int, 2, 3> mat2 = { { 7, 4, 9 },{ 8, 1, 5 } };

    auto mat3 = mat * mat2;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < mat3.rows(); ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < mat3.columns(); ++j)
            std::cout << mat3(i, j) << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: what does stop you from using `matrix<type_t, Rows, cls> ret_mat;` ?

Comment: Wow... I feel stupid now. Guess I need some rest. Thanks so much!!

Comment: I don't think you should allow multiplication of two `N*M` matrices for `N != M`. The maths just isn't right! You should only allow `[L*M] * [M*N]`, which is easily enforced with templates.

Comment: Why on earth are you storing an `initializer_list`?

Comment: Been a long night. It felt better than using std::list for some reason, mainly being able to input the matrices this way

Comment: `std::array` or `std::vector` would be better options.

Comment: @juanchopanza this isn't the full program. More checking is made to ensure the math is there :D

Comment: If by checking you mean compile time constraints with templates, then fine. But why post an incorrect example?

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry, I didn't want to make the post too big, so I cut out everything that wasn't needed for a successful compilation. And yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: The point is that getting that right would have required no more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<unsigned rws, unsigned cls>
```

You already have desired expressions!

```
matrix<type_t, Rows, cls> ret;
```

Edit: as mentioned by @juanchopanza, why are you allowing multiplication of N*M on K*L with M != K? Should be

```
template<unsigned cls>

auto operator*(matrix<type_t, columns, cls> &mat)
{
    matrix<type_t, Rows, cls> ret_mat;
```